# Menu icon not mapped to DrawerRouter Navigation - React Native Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation-drawer, native, react-native-navigation

For my project, I would like to have a Hamburger(menu) icon on the top left, clicking which should open the DrawerRouters on the left side. Totally, I have 5 Routes in DrawerRouters namely Login,"My Course","All Course", Profile, and Logout. Among these 5 Routers, 2("My Course","All Course") of them points to the same Stack Navigator(Custom stack, would be differentiating them using screenProps).

The problem is that the DrawerRouter is not opening if I click the menu icon displayed on each of the 5 screens. I will add my code and image below

[DrawerRoutes Page Image(MyRoutes)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMm1c.jpg)

[All Course Page Image(Course)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1xQZ.jpg)

App.js

```
export default class AppContainer extends React.Component {
    render() {
            return (<MyRoutes/>);
    }
}

Expo.registerRootComponent(AppContainer);
```

MyRoutes.js

```
const CustomStack = createStackNavigator({
    Course,
    ModuleList,
    LessonTabs,
    SectionList,
    SectionEdit,
});

class AllCourse extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <CustomStack screenProps={{courseType: 'ALL_COURSE'}}></CustomStack>)
    }
}

class MyCourse extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }
    render(){
        return(
        <CustomStack screenProps={{courseType: 'MY_COURSE'}}></CustomStack>)
    }
}

const DrawerRouter = createDrawerNavigator({
        Login: {
            screen: Login,
            navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
                title: 'Login Title',
            })
        },
        "My Courses": {
            screen: MyCourse,
            navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
                title: 'Mycourse Title',
            })
        },
        "All Courses": {
            screen: AllCourse,
            navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
                title: 'Allcourse Title',
            })
        },
        Profile: {
            screen: Profile,
            navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
                title: 'Profile Title',
            })
        },
        Logout: {
            screen: Logout,
            navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
                title: 'Logout Title',
            })
        }
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Login',
        contentOptions: {
            activeTintColor: '#548ff7',
            activeBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
            inactiveTintColor: '#ffffff',
            inactiveBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
            labelStyle: {
                fontSize: 15,
                marginLeft: 0,
            },
        },
        drawerWidth: SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.8,
        contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent,
        drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
        drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
        drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle',
    }
);

const CustomDrawerContentComponent = props => (
    <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#43484d'}}>
        <View style={{marginTop: 40, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
            <Text>Student World</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{marginLeft: 10}}>
            <DrawerItems {...props} />
        </View>
    </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#3498db',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
});

export default class MyRoutes extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<DrawerRouter/>);
    }
}
```

Course.js

```
export default class Course extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation}) => {
        return {
            title: "Courses",
            headerLeft: <Icon name="menu" size={70} onPress={ () => navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen') }/>,
        };
    };

    render() {
        return (<View><Text>Course Page</Text></View>);
    }
}
```

Inside Course page, the menu icon along with the title is displayed on the header, however, clicking it doesn't show the drawerRoute on the left side.

1) Im using DrawerOpen in the Course page to get the DrawerRoutes and its not working

```
headerLeft: <Icon name="menu" size={70} onPress={ () => navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen') }/>
```

2) How to bind Menu Icon with left DrawerRoutes

Answer (score 0):

You can add icon type and test again

**exemple :**

```
<Icon type="MaterialIcons" name="error-outline" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Added the above code but it is not working still